# Code was working fine but all of a sudden "The import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver cannot be resolved"

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, testng

I was following a udemy course and my code was working fine before but all of a sudden it crapped out and stopped working and I started getting "The import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver cannot be resolved" and "The import org.openqa.selenium.By cannot be resolved". Basically, anything importing from the selenium library.
I'm using selenium standalone 3.10

```
    package Demos;

import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.testng.Assert;
import org.testng.annotations.Test;

public class DemoTestNG {

    @Test
    public void test() {
        WebDriver driver = utilities.DriverFactory.open("chrome");
        driver.get("https://google.com");

        boolean searchbox = driver.findElement(By.name("q")).isDisplayed();
        Assert.assertTrue(searchbox);
    }

}
```

Any help would be appreciated. I don't want to keep reinstalling everything.

Comment: Which JDK you r using ?

Comment: In Eclipse.


Project -> Clean -> Clean All Projects

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are trying to run piece of code that hasn't compiled. See the problems tab in your IDE (If you are using `Eclipse`, the go to Windows-> Show View -> Other -> Problems). This will tell you why its not compiling. Solve these and you will be good to go.

Comment: Restarting eclipse seems to be a workaround(I know, I know), but if it happens again I'll try and see the problem and update. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Please check the project build path if it contains all the necessary dependencies. From your description, I am assuming the Selenium dependency is removed from project build path.

Please follow the below steps to check:

1. Right-Click on your project in Project Explorer
2. Click on Properties
3. Click on Java Build Path option on the left side of the project properties window
4. Click on Libraries tab
5. Check if `selenium-server-standalone-x.x.x.jar`is listed.
   If not, go ahead, add it, and re-run you code.

This should solve your issue.
If you still face issue, please feel free to comment back.

Comment: The jar is there, the code was working completely fine until it wasn't. Thank you though!